# Fullcalendar Remove Event On EventRender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

With fullcalendar, I want to remove events that are cancelled: those that have event.post_appt_status_id == '3'.

Right now in EventRender, I have icons that are prepended based on the appt status.  They work fine.  I thought that would be the place then to easily remove the cancelled events from the calendar.

It's just not working.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
   eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view) {

        //handle icon before time
        if(event.appt_status_id == '1'){         
            //confirmed icon
            element.find(".fc-time").prepend("<i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i> ");
        } else if(event.appt_status_id == '2'){         
            //unconfirmed icon
            element.find(".fc-time").prepend("<i class='fa fa-minus-square-o'></i> ");
        } else if(event.appt_status_id == '8'){         
            //walkin icon
            element.find(".fc-time").prepend("<i class='fa fa-male'></i> ");
        } else if(event.appt_status_id == '9'){         
            //left message icon
            element.find(".fc-time").prepend("<i class='fa fa-phone-square'></i> ");
        };

        //handle icon before title
        if(event.post_appt_status_id == '6'){         
            //attended alone icon
            element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-user'></i> ");
        } else if(event.post_appt_status_id == '7'){         
            //attended companion icon
            element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-users'></i> ");
        } else if(event.post_appt_status_id == '4'){         
            //no show icon
            element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> ");
        } else if(event.post_appt_status_id == '3'){         
            //cancelled icon
            element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-ban'></i> ");
            $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar('removeEvent', event.id);
        };

        //add text to event
        element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.appt_reason_name + " with " + event.scheduled_with_name); 

        //handle changing menu options at top
        return ['all', event.location_id].indexOf($('#calendar_location_id option:selected').val()) >= 0 && ['all', event.saw_by_id].indexOf($('#calendar_provider_id option:selected').val()) >= 0;

    },
```

I would have assumed that `$('#calendar_full').fullCalendar('removeEvent', event.id)` would remove those events from the calendar, but it's not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event rendering can be canceled if your [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) callback returns false.

> The function can also return false to completely cancel the rendering of the event.

```
eventRender: function( event, element, view ) {
       //...
       if (event.post_appt_status_id == '3') {
           return false;
       }
       //...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. This is what I needed.

Comment: if you call .fullCalendar('clientEvents') it still returns events that are not rendered. Can you remove the event in event render? Or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

the event you are trying to use has been removed from Plugin, they had introduced new one named as "removeEvents " .

For more details please check

https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/removeEvents/

OLD LINK

https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/removed/removeEvent/

Comment: So if I call alert(event.id) instead of $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id), all the events that are marked cancelled are alerted onscreen with the appropriate id.   If I use one of those event ids and call this function on an outside button click the event DOES get removed: $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar('removeEvents', 18323).    So you'd think it would get removed in EventRender, right?